# powershell ask to unlock user in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

not an expert in PowerShell but learning none the less.
I found 2 lines or 2 commands which could really help my job get done faster.

The goal would be to use the PowerShell to unlock a user and if it is locked, unlock it and I'm done. very simple.

How would I do that though. The logic behind it would be this:

- SHOW if user is locked

  - IF user is locked

    - THEN unlock
  - ELSE exit

Those 2 lines that I use is this :

```
Unlock-ADAccount -Identity "usernamehere"
Get-ADUser -Identity 'usernamehere' -Properties LockedOut | Select-Object Name, Lockedout
```

I know I can use the `Read-Host` to get some input from the user but that's where it stops for me though.

Best I could come up with is this:

```
$user = read-host -prompt 'Enter Username'
$lockedout = get-aduser $user -property lockedout | foreach { $_.LockedOut }
Write-Output "Account Locked: $($LockedOut)"
```

but it doesn't ask if I want to unlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline comments should help you understand the logic of the code. [`PSHostUserInterface.PromptForChoice` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.promptforchoice?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) is nice for this kind of things, this method will allow you to prompt user input with additional help messages and will also validate user input, meaning, **the user must provide the right input (`Y` or `N`)**.

```
$query = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Username'
$adUsr = Get-ADUser $user -Properties LockedOut
# if the user is locked
if($adUsr.LockedOut) {
    # what do we do here?
    $choice = $ExecutionContext.Host.UI.PromptForChoice(
        'Locked User',
        ('"{0}" is locked, would you like to unlock it?' -f $adUsr.SamAccountName),
        ('&Yes', '&No'),
        0 # => Default choice is `Yes`
    )
    # if choice was `Yes`
    if($choice -eq 0) {
        '"{0}" was sucessfully unlocked.' -f $adUsr.SamAccountName
    }
    # user was locked but it was decided to not unlock it
    else {
        # you can decide what to do here
    }
}
# else, if the user is not locked
else {
    '"{0}" is not locked. Goodbye.' -f $adUsr.SamAccountName
}
```

Comment: that works and I'll study those code lines.
i've noticed some kind of timeout error. If I do it again, it seems to work perfectly though. I bit odd but seems to work. Thank you very much